# How to display a circular progress indicator whilst waiting for Authentication from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a sign-in page that is authenticated by Firebase, and I want to display a circular progress indicator whilst is still authenticating.
I inserted if statements in the catch block of the sign-in button that handles the errors that may occur within the signing in process

I want to display the circular indicator if there's is no error that is thrown by the firebase Server
I am new to coding, please help me.

Below is a code of the sign-in page

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:user_details/fromJP/Scan_QR.dart';
import 'package:user_details/fromJP/load_widget.dart';
import 'Register.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool loading = false;

  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  String errorMessage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scafoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            key: _scafoldKey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Jinjer Pay"),
            ),
            body: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("lib/bg.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                decoration:
                                    new InputDecoration(hintText: "Email"),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                controller: _emailController,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                decoration:
                                    new InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                                obscureText: true,
                                enableSuggestions: false,
                                controller: _passwordController,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              RaisedButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Log In",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                elevation: 10,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    setState(() => loading = true);

                                    try {
                                      UserCredential res;
                                      String userID;

                                      res = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                              email: _emailController.text,
                                              password:
                                                  _passwordController.text));
                                      userID = res.user.uid;

                                      if (res == null) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          loading = false;
                                        });
                                      }
                                      if (res != null) {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => Scan_QR()),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    } catch (e) {
                                      if (e.code == "unknown") {
                                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                            msg:
                                                "Email/Password Field cannot be Empty",
                                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16.0);
                                      }
                                      if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
                                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                            msg: "Your password is incorrect",
                                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16.0);
                                      }
                                      if (e.code == "invalid-email") {
                                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                            msg:
                                                "Email/Password Field cannot be Empty",
                                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16.0);
                                      }
                                      if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
                                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                            msg:
                                                "No User found with this email",
                                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16.0);
                                      }
                                      if (e.code == "user-disabled") {
                                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                            msg:
                                                "user with this email has been disabled",
                                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16.0);
                                      }
                                      if (e.code == "too-many-requests") {
                                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                            msg:
                                                "Too many requests, try again later",
                                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                            textColor: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16.0);
                                      }
                                      print(e);
                                      //_emailController.text = "";
                                      _passwordController.text = "";
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    "Not Registered? ",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => Register()),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Register",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 19),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `showDialog` with `Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator())` in `try` block and `Navigator.pop(context);` when you succeeded or get thrown error

Comment: I do not understand your answer

Comment: I have edited my question with regards to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bool isLoading property in your widget that initializes to false. then in your function call you can set the state and change your isLoading to true before making the call to firebase. when the call to firebase completes either successfully or throws an error you can then set the state and change isLoading to false again.

Finally, in the UI you can use conditionals to show a circular progress indicator if isLoading is true.

Comment: I have edited my question with regards to your answer

Comment: Does it show the loading indicator now?
Also, I would not use the loading conditional with the scaffold as you are doing now. This would cause that when the loading is true you would remove the scaffold and that might look very bad to the user.

Additionally, you will have to re-render the entire page when you set the is loading to false again. A better option would be to put the conditional check further down the widget tree where it is needed.

Comment: I added validation statements in the TextFormFields, that validates before loading the Progress circular Indicator, then if theres is an error from the serverit returns that error in a toast.

Answer (score 0):

I added this block at the beginning of the catch block

```
if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid != e.code)
                                        {
                                          setState(() {
                                            loading = false;
                                          });
                                        }
```